# gpiodetect does not find a GPIO device

Tags: ftdi, ubuntu-20.04

I have a  [FT2232H-56Q Mini Module](https://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Modules/DevelopmentModules.htm#FT2232H-56_Mini) and can't detect GPIOs with gpiodetect using Ubuntu 20.04 and Kernel 5.4.

Seems to be similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60781594/ft232h-user-space-gpio-device) but it should actually be fixed in Kernel 5.4.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Well, do you have further information? What have you tried so far? Is the device recognized as a VCP port or is the D2XX been loaded?

Comment: Thank you, the VCP vs D2XX is probably the cause of my problem. I was just wondering, as I browsed the Linux Kernel sources I saw a gpio.h in the ftdi driver, so I thought that it works instantly. At least that's how it works with Silabs' CP201X.